# Change in web config results in "Could not find assembly..." error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, iis-7.5

I've come across an unbelievably stupid situation with my ASP.NET MVC application hosted in IIS 7.5. Here's the case:

1. I publish the application to the server and test it. It works just fine
2. I change anything in the web.config file and then undo the change. So it's in its original state
3. I test the application again but this time I get
   `Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.` error.

Please note this: I just open the web.config file and edit and then immediately undo that edit. It doesn't matter in which line of which section I make edit. (After all, aren't configuration files there to not have to touch the code?)

Now comes more interesting part.

4. I copy and paste the latest published files to the application folder
5. test the application: Still get the same error
6. I republish the application and copy/paste to the folder, **EXCEPT FOR THE WEB.CONFIG FILE**. So I don't even touch the "damaged" config file.
7. Test it, voila, it works.

I just don't get it. Do you have any clue about this issue?

Comment: Does this happen every time you make a change to the web.config file?

Comment: I've tried this whole process at least 5 times. Yes, every time, without any exception.

Comment: Have you tried to recyle the website and the app pool?

Comment: No, I haven't. But there's an option in the Advanced settings of the app pool called `Disable Recycling fro configuration Change` which is false by default, which means IIS itself does it. But I'll give a try and let you know.

Comment: @sjokkogutten, I tried recycling, it doesn't help.

Comment: In your app pool can use set 'Enable 32-Bit applications' to TRUE? Explained [here](https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/kb/a1114/how-to-enable-32-bit-application-pool-iis-7-dedicatedvps.aspx)

Comment: It's already set to true. But I can't see any relevance to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a third party tool called EntityFramework Profiler with which I traced SQL commands issued by Entity Framework.  After removing it from the application, the problem disappeared.